# Assertion error in Clojure's deftest macro if comparing lists

Tags: clojure, clojure-testing

My question ist about Clojures deftest macro or more generally about how to compare lists created by functions. But i´m new to Clojure and can´t recognize the specific cause. Maybe anyone else have an idea?

First the reported message:

> FAIL in (to-symbol-list-test) (util_test.clj:105)
>   
> expected: (= (quote (a (not b) c)) (to-symbol-list ["a" "(not b)" "c"]))
> actual: (not (= (a (not b) c) (a (not b) c)))

But it is obviously that (= (a (not b) c) (a (not b) c)) quoted should be true instead.

Second the specific test code:

```
(deftest to-symbol-list-test 
(is (= '(a (not b) c) (to-symbol-list ["a" "(not b)" "c"]))))
```

Third the definition of to-symbol-list:

```
(defn to-symbol-list [term]
  "Converts a vector based term into a list based term
  by converting its elements into symbols recursivly"
  (postwalk
    #(if (string? %)
       (symbol %)
       (reverse (into '() %)))
    term))
```

The function even should convert nested vectors. It´s an example, other functions behave in the same manner. I guessed it could cause by different types. For example list vs lazy-seq and i compare the lazy function instead of the data, but the types seems to be correct. In REPL i get:

```
(type (to-symbol-list ["a" "(not b)" "c"]))
=> clojure.lang.PersistentList
```

Comment: I think you are falling trap to `(symbol "(not b)")`

Comment: You are right thats the problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to-symbol-list` returns a list of 3 symbols, and doesn't recursively deal with the nested data structure. Unfortunately the second symbol prints the same as the correctly parsed data structure you're expecting. I think in this case you'd be better off using `clojure.edn/read-string` ([docs here](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.edn-api.html)) which will parse your data structure as I think you're expecting.

```
(defn to-symbol-list [list-of-strings]
  (map edn/read-string list-of-strings))

(to-symbol-list ["a" "(not b)" "c"])
```

Also, as a hint to help diagnose this sort of thing in the future, you can pass an extra argument to `clojure.test/is` which will print out in the event of a failure. This can be the result of a function call, like:

```
(ns to-symbols-test
  (:require [clojure.edn :as edn]
            [clojure.test :refer [deftest is are testing] :as t]
            [clojure.data :as data]
            [clojure.pprint :as pp]))

(defn to-symbol-list [l]
  (map edn/read-string l))

(defn diff [a b]
  (with-out-str (pp/pprint (take 2 (data/diff a b)))))

(deftest test-to-symbol-list
  (testing "to-symbol-list should convert recursively"
    (let [expected '(a (not b) c)
          result   (to-symbol-list ["a" "(not b)" "c"])]
      (is (= expected result (diff expected result))))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer and the clue with diff. Merging your function with mine solved the evaluation to true. Merging because with recursive i didn´t mean going down in the string, but rather even parse something like this: ["or"
      ["and" "(not a)" "b" "c"]
      ["and" "a" "(not b)" "c"]
      ["and" "a" "b" "(not c)"]
      ["and" "a" "b" "c"]]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `to-symbol-list` turns `"(not b)"` string a symbol, but not a nested list. To fix that, you'll need to refactor that function to take parens into account. Say, if it sees `(` as the first symbol of a string, it calls itself recursively appending the result into some kind of accumulator (SICP is full of such exercises by the way).